# Update a Column When Inserting a Record in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table `Conservation_Dev` with these columns (amongst 30 other):

- `I3_IDENTITY` - a `BIGINT` and a unique key
- `STATE` - a 2-letter US state abbreviation
- `ZONE` - when I want to store the time zone for this record

I also have a table `TimeZoneCodes` that maps US states to time zones (forget the fact that some states are in more than one time zone):

- `state_code` - the 2-letter abbreviation for the state
- `time_zone` - the text with the time zone (EST, CST, etc)

I have data being loaded into `Conservation_Dev` without the time zone data and that is something that I can't control. I want to create an after insert trigger that updates the record. Doing some research on previous threads I came up with the following:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[PopulateTimeZoneBasedOnUSState]
ON [dbo].[Conservation_Dev]
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN   
    UPDATE [dbo].[Conservation_Dev]
    SET [ZONE] = (SELECT [time_zone] 
                  FROM [dbo].[TimeZoneCodes] Z 
                  WHERE Z.[state_code] = i.[STATE])
    FROM Inserted i
    WHERE [I3_IDENTITY] = i.[I3_IDENTITY]
END
```

I get an error, though:

> Ambiguous column name 'I3_IDENTITY'

Also, is this the right way to do this? Will this be a problem if the data load is, say, 5 or 10 thousand records at a time through an SSIS import package?

Comment: Why don't you use the lookups component in SSIS to add the timezone as column so the data is there for insert? Triggers are not always the best answer for this, because they are not easily visible for someone maintaining the code later, data appears to populate from nowhere.

Comment: I don't have access to the SSIS package. I don't have any control over that process.

Comment: I think you are right...

Comment: If you're worried about the overhead of a trigger on each insert, why not take the SQL from below that gets you the correct result and put it into a procedure.  Edit it to only update rows that have a timezone of null, and then you can run the procedure in a job on a schedule.  This will reduce the overhead of the trigger being triggered on every row, but it will mean that the rows are not update immediately after insert.  Also note, if you do not have permissions to create a trigger, you probably do not have them to make a procedure and/or a job.

Comment: The update to the Zone column needs to happen when the record is inserted. For different reasons that don't belong to this forum, I need to use a trigger. I can't change anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My vote would be to move this update into the SSIS package so that the insert of data is all in one place. I may then move to a stored procedure that runs after the data is loaded. A trigger is going to happen on every insert. I think table based queries/updates would have a better performance. Triggers can be hard to find from a troubleshooting standpoint, but if they are well documented then it may not be much of an issue. The trigger will allow the Zone to be populated once a record is inserted.

The problem with the trigger you are creating is because SQL Server doesn't know which I3_IDENTITY you are referring to in the first part of the `WHERE` clause. This should fix it:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[PopulateTimeZoneBasedOnUSState]
ON [dbo].[Conservation_Dev]
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN   
    UPDATE [dbo].[Conservation_Dev]
    SET [ZONE] = (SELECT TOP 1 [time_zone] FROM [dbo].[TimeZoneCodes] Z WHERE Z.[state_code] = i.[STATE])
    FROM Inserted i
    WHERE [dbo].[Conservation_Dev].[I3_IDENTITY] = i.[I3_IDENTITY]
END
```

This would be a table level update that will update all time_zones in one sweep. I would use something like this in a stored procedure after the initial inserts were complete.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.UpdateAllZones   
AS 
 Update dbo.Conservation_Dev
 SET Zone = Time_Zone
 From dbo.Conservation_Dev c INNER JOIN dbo.TimeZoneCodes z ON c.state_code = z.state_code
Go
```

Executed as
 `EXEC dbo.UpdateAllZones`

Comment: I don't have access to how the data is loaded. It's done by a third party. Which solution will be more efficient in performance? The one with the JOINs above or this one?

Comment: Try them both and watch the execution plan. Your original update is the quickest. It will select and find the value from 5k records and insert the value. By using JOINs you will join 5k to 10k records on every insert which will have you looking at searching much more. JOINs can be expensive.

Comment: I can't create SPs. I only own what's related to this table. There's many other things in the DB that I don't control or maintain. My only choice is the trigger. The question is if using the JOIN version or the SELECT version.

Comment: Use the select version

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[PopulateTimeZoneBasedOnUSState]
ON [dbo].[Conservation_Dev]
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN   
    UPDATE A
    SET A.[ZONE] = Z.[time_zone]
    FROM [dbo].[Conservation_Dev] as A
    INNER JOIN Inserted as i
    ON A.[I3_IDENTITY] = i.[I3_IDENTITY]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[TimeZoneCodes] as Z 
    ON Z.[state_code] = i.[STATE]
END
```

Comment: This is not giving me any error and it looks good. Unfortunately I just found out I can't create a trigger due to permissions! I will try to work that out but I'll select yours as the answer. If when the trigger runs there are any issues I'll let you know. Now, do you know of any potential issues when inserting 5 to 10 K records at a time?

Comment: @Amarundo The problem is that for every one record you insert, you are joining 5k to 10k records. Then you search through that to insert your value. The update you already have will search through the 5k to 10k records for a single value and then inserts it. (should be much faster) Joins are expensive and especially if you are going to join 5k to 10k records 5k to 10k times as you receive records from SSIS.